# Do I need to buy/play certain DLC from the previous games to get access to certain squad mates?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What squad mates will I miss from not importing from the previous games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54940/what-squad-mates-will-i-miss-from-not-importing-from-the-previous-games)

Do I need to have purchased and/or played through any DLC for Mass Effect or Mass Effect 2 in order to have access to certain squad mates in Mass Effect 3?

That is, are there any squad mates exclusively available from DLC for ME/ME2 that are later featured in Mass Effect 3?

Comment: Closing this because it is a subset of the duplicate, even though this came first.

Comment: I see it as a separate question, I guess. The situation I'm imagining is a player with both the first two games, but none of the DLC. The player wants a full cast for ME3, but doesn't know the answer to the above question. The secondary question that you refer to as a duplicate does not handle this case.

Comment: As my answer on the duplicate states: the only exclusive squadmate is from ME3 DLC. Otherwise, DLC and lack of import means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No, none of the DLC squadmates from ME/ME2 are squadmates in this game.

"From Ashes" - the day 1 ME3 DLC that is included with the Collector's Edition - features a new squadmate, however.